# On the Stack Overflow team page, the sidebar menu collides with the footer when scrolled all the way down

Tags: bug, design, stackexchange.com, stack-exchange-team

When I go to the [Stack Overflow Team page](https://stackoverflow.com/company/team) and scroll all the way down, I see this collision:

[image: Collision/Flooding Alarm!]

The sidebar menu should probably not scroll once it hits the footer.

I'm using Chrome, if it matters.

Comment: One of the most reported bugs here... you should be more active in MSE, Jon. ;-)